# C# Use discard '_'

Tags: c#, .net

I'm not quite sure of the different between

```
DataTable itemTable = new DataTable();
itemTable = //CODE
```

and

```
_ = new DataTable();
DataTable itemTable = //CODE
```

Both worked exactly the same, why would I need to change it to an _ like shown?

IMAGE OF THE "POTENTIAL FIX"

[image]

Comment: Why are you doing this in the first place?

Comment: So you're assigning something to `itemTable` then immediately reassigning something else to it. If we knew *why* you wrote the original code we might be able to help better.

Comment: @Sean I'm grabbing all entries in RentalItems which is converted into a DataTable and binding it to a DataGridView

Comment: The information Visual Studio gives you is that you aren't doing anything with that `new DataTable()` as you instantly discard it when you reassign `Context.GetDataTable(...,...)` to `itemTable`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because you have not used the value `new DataTable()` after assigning, the intellisense thought that you won't need it, so just made the leftside wildcard.

Its just like:

```
int a = 5;
a = 6; // you didn't even used the value 5 assigned above!
```

*But*, in case that the constructor of `DataTable` has side-effect, the intellisense suggested you not to discard the entire statement, using wildcard _. That's what happened.

If the constructor of `DataTable` has no side-effect, you are free to remove the statement, just like the above `int` example.

Comment: Yea, makes sense. I completely forgot that I was assigning a new DataTable I wasn't even using.

Answer (score 3):

**Both**:

```
DataTable itemTable = new DataTable();
itemTable = //CODE
```

and:

```
_ = new DataTable();
DataTable itemTable = //CODE
```

seem wrong to me.

In both cases you have an assignment in the first line which is useless.

There are two ways to make it better, depending on whether the `new DataTable()` expression has side effects.

---

In the most frequent and good case, the allocation of a new `DataTable` in the first line can be omitted completely. You then write:

```
DataTable itemTable;
itemTable = //CODE
```

The first line declares the local variable. The second line assigns it. However, it is much more common to put these two things together in one statement, namely:

```
DataTable itemTable = //CODE
```

This is the one you should use.

Often you would use an implicit type with `var`. The variable will still be strongly typed:

```
var itemTable = //CODE
```

If the type of the expression `//CODE` is `DataTable`, this is entirely equivalent to what you had before. If the (compile-time) type of the right-hand side is instead something more specific, say `YourItemDataTable`, then using `var` will give the local variable that more specific type as well. That may very well be fine. So very often, it is appropriate to use `var`, but it is also a matter of style.

---

In the unlikely (theoretically possible) scenario where the initialization of a `new` object instance is intended and needed (a constructor may have side effects), C# allows a `new`-object expression to be a statement by itself. So in that case, write:

```
new DataTable();
DataTable itemTable = //CODE
```

The language has a support for this situation, but I doubt it is useful. When `DataTable` is the one in the `System.Data.dll` assembly, it is not relevant.

Comment: Yea, I picked up on that. I removed the _ = new DataTable it's fine now. Thanks :)