# What do the terms "context" and "_context" mean in .NET Core?

Tags: c#

Can someone explain the meaning of these two terms to me: *"_context" and "context"*?

Coming from Basic, Pascal, and ASPX (VB) to C# and Razor pages, I constantly misunderstand the recent .NET terminology. I believe that the only essential context (that's referred to as such) in my database application is *the* context - that is, a class deriving from DbContext that handles database connections. However, this always seems to be handled in an oblique way. I see examples in tutorials like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/update-related-data?view=aspnetcore-7.0):

```
public class CreateModel : DepartmentNamePageModel
    {
        private readonly ContosoUniversity.Data.SchoolContext _context;

        public CreateModel(ContosoUniversity.Data.SchoolContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
```

If the first line within the function is creating a new instance of *the* context, why (since I already have this defined and able to list items from my tables) do I get a syntax error

> The name '_context' does not exist in the current context"

when I adapt it into my own code? I've added all the references from the top of the example pages. Why do we need a model within a model here, and what does the last statement do?

I've looked in this tutorial for clarification and done searches, but everything I read seems to assume we're already fluent in this way of using objects. I particularly need to grasp this because the only working example of a dropdown I can find uses these cross-references, and what I expected to be a simple task has tied me in knots.

Comment: You seem to be getting hung up on local variables vs class level fields. It really has nothing to do with an Entity Framework context. You can read more about fields [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields). The underscore in front of the field is just a convention that some people use to make it clear that it's a field.

Comment: Although it sounds like you have some programming background, I think dependency injection might be the cause of your misunderstanding. The CreateModel constructor is taking in a SchoolContext as a parameter. DI is providing this context "out of thin air" for you. In order for the SchoolContext to be in scope for the rest of the methods within the CreateModel class, the constructor is assigning the private readonly local member to point to the instance of the SchoolContext incoming parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constructor gets an instance of `ContosoUniversity.Data.SchoolContext` (injected, for example) and then you set it to a field called `_context`. Both variables are referencing the same object. If you didn't want to have two different names, you would use "this" like this:

```
public class CreateModel : DepartmentNamePageModel
{
    private readonly ContosoUniversity.Data.SchoolContext context;

    public CreateModel(ContosoUniversity.Data.SchoolContext context)
    {
        this.context = context; // "this" refers to the field defined in this class and not the parameter of the constructor
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Francisco's example using "this" was very helpful as that syntax makes more sense to me than an underscore. Looks as if I need to study and repeat a few more tutorials before I have enough understanding to create anything usable in the new domain.

Comment: @TyneBridges .NET started encouraging users to switch from `this.` to `_` syntax I think about 10-15 years ago. I'm no expert, but I think anywhere you see `_` preceding a variable in .NET, you can still use `this.` instead. In other words, `_` is simply shorthand for `this.`

Comment: @TylerH: I'm afraid it doesn't work like that. `_` is a part of the identifier. `this`, in contrast, is a keyword that specifies the instance on which you access a member. If you see a field name like `_context`, you cannot just write `this.context` - `this.context` and `this._context` are two different fields! And you also cannot write `this._context` unless you really want to access `_context` on the instance you are currently operating from, and not e.g. `other._context` (with `other` being another instance).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I was suggesting `this.context`, not `this._context`, instead of `_context`. If you type `this.context` in code like Francisco's code above, Visual Studio will suggest you change it to `_context` for example. Essentially _anywhere_ you use `this.<variablename>`, Visual Studio's wizard will suggest that you change it to `_<variablename>` instead.

Comment: @TylerH: "Essentially anywhere you use this.<variablename>, Visual Studio's wizard will suggest that you change it to _<variablename> instead." - sorry, that's simply not true. VS will suggest `_context` precisely when only the identifier `_context` was declared in your scope, but not `context`. If you have declared `context` as, e.g., a field in your class, then *that declaration* may get a squiggly line with a suggestion to change the name, but everywhere else, VS will happily accept `this.context` as that is the name of the field.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Well, I dunno what to tell ya; I have seen VS recommend `_` countless times where I have definitely not already declared something with `_` in that scope, for the last 5 years at least.  And of course VS will happily accept `this.context` because that's still valid code. See [this](https://cosmin-vladutu.medium.com/c-this-vs-underscore-646f777be59) (admittedly poorly-written) blog post for more info on what I am talking about. At some point (probably with the advent of .NET Core) the floodgates opened in terms of MSFT recommending `_` to everyone and people all finally using it.

Comment: @TylerH: "I have seen VS recommend `_` countless times" - very curious. I just tried again; first I added a private member without an underscore, e.g. `private int abc;`, then I accessed it using `abc = 25;`, and at no point in the `abc = 25;` does VS say anything about adding an underscore. The only place where that happens is in the declaration, like I wrote above. The environment where I just tried is VS 2022 Pro with ReSharper, maybe somewhat different versions or setups behave differently in that respect?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I don't have Resharper, but I would expect a comparison to be in a declaration using the scheme `this.<variable>`, not just `<variable>`. As mentioned above, for example, `this.context [...]` shows a lightbulb on the side and suggests `_context`. However, just `context [...]` would not. After further searching for the 'name' of this phenomenon, I may be overlapping it with the 'use discard' situation (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60946090/c-sharp-use-discard)

Comment: @TylerH: `this.` can only appear in expressions, not in a declaration (at least not in the narrow sense, just the `<type> <identifer>` part, without the assignment of e.g. an initial value). Also, [*discards*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/discards), i.e. underscores that form a complete token of their own, are special syntax elements with a special meaning in C#, which is something very different from an underscore character that happens to appear as a part of an identifier and has, beyond stylistic considerations, no special meaning there.